# Dimension and Spanning

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$, let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ and let $S \subset W$. Use dimension to justify that:

If $\text{span}(S) = W$, then $\text{dim}(W) \leq |S|.$

Workings:

I believe it has to do with the fact that any set of  any set of fewer than $n$ vectors cannot be a spanning set.

So since $S$ spans, there has to be more than $n$ vectors which is equivalent to $\text{dim}(W)$.

Therefore $\text{dim}(W) \leq |S|.$

Is my reasoning correct? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Help:   For any set $S$, $dim( span(S) )\leq |S|.$ In the special case where $S$ is a linearly independent set, then  $dim( span(S) ) = |S|,$ by the definition of $dim$. If it is linearly dependent set, then  $dim( span(S) )< |S|.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be vector space over F. Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ and $S\subset W$.

Also, $Span(S)=W$, we need to show $dim(W)\leq |S|$

A simple fact: $dim(Span(S))$ is at most $|S|$ (It will be maximum when the elements of S are linearly independent).

Now, $Span(S)=W$, therefore, $dim(W)\leq |S|$.